# Differentiation uner the integral sign - help me find my mistake

Tags: calculus, integration

This is my integral:
$$I(a)=\int_0^\infty\frac {\ln(a^2+x^2)}{(b^2+x^2)}dx.$$

Taking the first derivative with respect to a:

$$I'(a)=\int_0^\infty \frac {2adx} {(a^2+x^2)(b^2+x^2)}.$$
This is how I did the partial fraction decomposition:
$\frac {2a} {(a^2+x^2)(b^2+x^2)}=\frac {Ax+B} {(a^2+x^2)}+\frac {Cx+D} {(b^2+x^2)}$.

From here I get that $A=C=0$, $B=\frac {2a} {(b^2-a^2)}$ and $D=\frac {-2a} {(b^2-a^2)}$

Is this correct? Because when I try to solve $I'(a)$ using these values for $B$ and $D$ I get a different solution from the textbook?

Comment: Why don't you actually *include* what you get for $I'(a)$ and then what the book gets so others can see what the comparison of the end results is? Otherwise you're leaving us in the dark about what you wound up with. That doesn't help others help you.

Comment: What is the original integral you are attempting to solve?

Comment: Btw, once you have this one under your belt you should move to:

$$
I(a,b,c) = \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln\left(a^2 + x^2\right)}{\left(b^2 + x^2\right)\left(c^2 + x^2\right)}\:dx
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let’s redo the work$$\frac 1{(a^2+x^2)(b^2+x^2)}=\frac {Ax+B}{a^2+x^2}+\frac {Cx+D}{b^2+x^2}$$Multiplying both sides by the common denominator$$1=(Ax+B)(b^2+x^2)+(Cx+D)(a^2+x^2)$$To find values for $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$, first set $x^2=-a^2$. Thus$$\begin{align*}1 & =(Ax+B)(b^2-a^2)\\ & =Ax(b^2-a^2)+B(b^2-a^2)\end{align*}$$Therefore, it’s easy to see that $A=0$ and $B=1/(b^2-a^2)$. Now do a similar procedure for the other term by setting $x^2=-b^2$. Thus$$\begin{align*}1 & =(Cx+D)(a^2-b^2)\\ & =Cx(a^2-b^2)+D(a^2-b^2)\end{align*}$$Thus, $C=0$ and $D=1/(a^2-b^2)$. So to sum everything up$$\frac 1{(a^2+x^2)(b^2+x^2)}\color{blue}{=\frac 1{(b^2-a^2)(a^2+x^2)}+\frac 1{(a^2-b^2)(b^2+x^2)}}$$

Comment: Great, thanks a lot, finally I found my mistake and got the correct solution!

Answer (score 1):

Here you are solving:

\begin{equation}
I(a,b)=\int_0^\infty\frac {\ln\left(a^2+x^2\right)}{\left(b^2+x^2\right)}dx
\end{equation}

The method you have taken is perfectly fine. Here I will employ Feynman's Trick and introduce a new parameter:
\begin{equation}
J(t;a,b)=\int_0^\infty\frac {\ln\left(a^2+tx^2\right)}{\left(b^2+x^2\right)}dx
\end{equation}
We see that $I(a,b) = \lim_{t \rightarrow 1^+} J(t;a,b)$ and that $J(0;a,b)$ is easy to resolve (will do later). Applying Leibniz's Integral Rule we take the derivative with respect to $t$:

\begin{align}
\frac{dJ}{dt} &= \int_0^\infty\frac {x^2}{\left(a^2 + tx^2\right)\left(b^2+x^2\right)}dx = \frac{1}{b^2t - a^2}\int_0^\infty\left[\frac{b^2}{b^2 + x^2} - \frac{a^2}{a^2+tx^2} 
 \right]dx \\
&= \frac{1}{b^2t - a^2}\left[\left|b\right|\operatorname{arctan}\left(\frac{x}{\left|b\right|} \right) - \frac{\left|a\right|}{\sqrt{t}} \operatorname{arctan}\left(\frac{\sqrt{t}x}{\left|a\right|}\right)
 \right]_0^\infty \\
&=\frac{1}{b^2t - a^2}\left[\left|b\right|\cdot \frac{\pi}{2} -\frac{\left|a\right|}{\sqrt{t}}\cdot \frac{\pi}{2}\right] =\frac{\pi}{2\left(b^2t - a^2\right)}\left[\left|b\right|\ -\frac{\left|a\right|}{\sqrt{t}}\right] = \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{t}\left(b^2t - a^2\right)}\left[\left|b\right|\sqrt{t} -\left|a\right|\right] \\
&=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{t}\left(\left|b\right|\sqrt{t} + \left|a\right|\right)}
\end{align}
We now integrate with respect to $t$:
\begin{equation}
J(t;a,b) = \int \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{t}\left(\left|b\right|\sqrt{t} + \left|a\right|\right)}\:dt
\end{equation}
Here let $t = u^2$
\begin{align}
 &\int \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{t}\left(\left|b\right|\sqrt{t} + \left|a\right|\right)}\:dt =  \int \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{u^2}\left(\left|b\right|\sqrt{u^2} + \left|a\right|\right)}\cdot 2u\:du = \int \frac{\pi}{\left|b\right||u| + \left|a\right|}\:du \\
&= \frac{\pi}{|b|}\ln\left|\left|b\right||u| + \left|a\right| \right| + C = \frac{\pi}{|b|}\ln\left|\left|b\right|\sqrt{t} + \left|a\right| \right| + C
\end{align}

Where $C$ is the constant of integration.To resolve we use $J(0;a,b)$:
\begin{equation}
J(0;a,b) = \int_0^\infty\frac {\ln\left(a^2+0\cdot x^2\right)}{\left(b^2+x^2\right)}dx = \frac{\pi}{|b|}\ln\left|\left|b\right|\sqrt{0} + \left|a\right| \right| + C =  \frac{\pi}{|b|}\ln\left|ab \right| + C 
\end{equation}
And thus
\begin{align}
 \frac{\pi}{|b|}\ln\left|ab \right| + C&= \int_0^\infty\frac {\ln\left(a^2\right)}{\left(b^2+x^2\right)}dx = 2\ln|a| \int_0^\infty\frac {1}{\left(b^2+x^2\right)}dx\\
& =  2\ln|a| \left[\frac{1}{\left|b\right|}\operatorname{arctan\left(\frac{x}{\left|b\right|} \right)} 
\right]_0^\infty = 2\ln|a| \cdot \frac{1}{\left|b\right|} \frac{\pi}{2} = \frac{\pi\ln|a|}{|b|}
\end{align}
Thus

\begin{equation}
C = \frac{\pi\ln|a|}{|b|} - \frac{\pi}{|b|}\ln\left|ab \right| = -\frac{\pi}{|b|}\ln|b|
\end{equation}

Thus, we form our solutions for $J(t;a,b)$:

\begin{equation}
J(t;a,b) = \frac{\pi}{|b|}\ln\left|\left|b\right| \sqrt{t}+ \left|a\right| \right| -\frac{\pi}{|b|}\ln|b|
\end{equation}

We now can solve for $I(a,b)$ by applying the limit as above:

\begin{align}
I(a,b) &= \lim_{t \rightarrow 1^+} J(t;a,b) = \lim_{t \rightarrow 1^+}\frac{\pi}{|b|}\ln\left|\left|b\right| \sqrt{t}+ \left|a\right| \right| -\frac{\pi}{|b|}\ln|b| \\
&= \frac{\pi}{|b|}\ln\left|\left|b\right| + \left|a\right| \right| -\frac{\pi}{|b|}\ln|b| =\frac{\pi}{|b|}\ln\left|\frac{\left|b\right| + \left|a\right|}{|b|} \right|
\end{align}

Or

\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty\frac {\ln\left(a^2+x^2\right)}{\left(b^2+x^2\right)}dx = \frac{\pi}{|b|}\ln\left|\frac{\left|b\right| + \left|a\right|}{|b|} \right|
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

$$I(a)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln(a^2+x^2)}{(b^2+x^2)}dx$$
$$I'(a)=\int_0^\infty\frac{2a}{(a^2+x^2)(b^2+x^2)}dx$$
now we want to look at simplifying this expression:
$$\frac{2a}{(a^2+x^2)(b^2+x^2)}$$
and we know (due to both factors being quadratic) that it will be of the form:
$$\frac{2a}{(a^2+x^2)(b^2+x^2)}=\frac{Ax+B}{a^2+x^2}+\frac{Cx+D}{b^2+x^2}$$
$$2a=(Ax+B)(b^2+x^2)+(Cx+D)(a^2+x^2)$$
firstly if we look at the cubic terms:
$$0=Ax^3+Cx^3$$
now at the quadratic terms:
$$0=Bx^2+Dx^2$$
now at the linear terms:
$$0=Ab^2x+Ca^2x$$
and finally the constants:
$$2a=Bb^2+Da^2$$
From this we obtain the following simultaneous equations:
$$A+C=0$$
$$B+D=0$$
$$Ab^2+Ca^2=0$$
$$Bb^2+Da^2-2a=0$$
This should give: $A=0$, $C=0$, $B=1/(b^2-a^2)$, $D=1/(a^2-b^2)$

If we put this back in we get:
$$I'(a)=\int_0^\infty\left[\frac{1}{b^2-a^2}\frac{1}{a^2+x^2}+\frac{1}{a^2-b^2}\frac{1}{b^2+x^2}\right]dx$$
we can now split this up into parts to make it easier:
$$I_1=\frac{1}{b^2-a^2}\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{a^2+x^2}dx=\frac{1}{a^2(b^2-a^2)}\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{1+(x/a)^2}dx$$
letting $x=a\tan(u)$ we get $dx=a\sec^2(u)du$ giving:
$$I_1=\frac{1}{a(b^2-a^2)}\int_0^{\pi/2}du=\frac{\pi}{2}\times\frac{1}{a(b^2-a^2)}$$
Similarly we can obtain:
$$I_2=\frac{1}{a^2-b^2}\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{b^2+x^2}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}\times\frac{1}{b(a^2-b^2)}$$
Which gives us:
$$I'(a)=\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\frac{1}{a(b^2-a^2)}+\frac{1}{b(a^2-b^2)}\right)$$
we know now that we must integrate this to obtain an expression for $I(a)$ and work out the constant of integration. To clarify:
$$I(a)=\int\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\frac{1}{a(b^2-a^2)}+\frac{1}{b(a^2-b^2)}\right)da+C$$
To make it easier we will split this up again:
$$I_3=\int\frac{1}{a(b^2-a^2)}da$$
$$I_4=\int\frac{1}{b(a^2-b^2)}da$$
To make this shorter I will just show the answer:
$$I_3=-\frac{\ln|a^2-b^2|-2\ln|a|}{2b^2}$$
$$I_4=-\frac{\ln|a+b|-\ln|a-b|}{2b^2}$$
Giving:
$$I(a)=-\frac{\pi}{4b^2}\left(\ln|a^2-b^2|-2\ln|a|+\ln|a+b|-\ln|a-b|\right)+C$$
Normally this value of $C$ would be calculated where a value of $a$ can be inputted which makes the integral $I(a)$ trivial, its not so easy here but $a=0$ seems the best option

Comment: Hmm $a = 0$ may be a problem with your $\ln|a|$ term...

Comment: True. A value may have to be calculated numerically for some other value of $a$ then @DavidG

Comment: Btw - I found the solution (method below) to be:

$$\int_0^\infty\frac {\ln\left(a^2+x^2\right)}{\left(b^2+x^2\right)}dx = \frac{\pi}{|b|}\ln\left|\frac{\left|b\right| + \left|a\right|}{|b|} \right|$$